# Uncaught TypeError: (this.getProductList(...) || []).map is not a function

Tags: reactjs

In the react app, I am setting the default value to [] and trying to return same in case shop.product does not exist. Still getting the ERROR : (this.getProductList() || []).map is not a function if the list returned is empty.

```
class Product extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);    
        this.state = {
            resultsFallback: { items: [] }
        }
    }

    getProductList(){

        let productNamesApi = this.state.resultsFallback;

        if (userStr.product) {
            // do something
            productNamesApi updated
        } 
        return productNamesApi;
    }

}

render {
    return { (this.getProductList() || []) }
}
```

Comment: What is possible return values from `this.getProductList()` method? And what is the error message you are getting?

Comment: it will be array : [] example : "product":"A,B,C,D"

Comment: so ui is as:
depending on Shop: I loop over product list. 
Some shops do not have any product so I get null/undefined. 
I am returning 'resultsFallback' for them which is declared in the State of react... 

ERROR message : this.getProductList() || []).map is not a function as this.getProductList() is returning 'resultsFallback' for these

Comment: Can you console log `getProductList` before returning it and see what is the value?

Answer (score 0):

The value of your `productNamesApi` is a object and not an array, in this case it's `{ items: [] }`.

Then you return the `productNamesApi` in `getProductList()`, so the value of your `getProductList()` is now an object of `{ items: [] }`

There is no `.map()` function in an object so the `{ items: [] }.map()` will throw a `.map() is not a function` error.

If you wan't to return the value of `items` array inside your `resultsFallback` state, you can try this.

```js
getProductList(){
    let productNamesApi = this.state.resultsFallback;

    if (userStr.product) {
        // do something
        // productNamesApi updated
    } 
    return productNamesApi.items;
}
```

So that you have a value of `getProductList()` as array of items

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help. I forgot to update but changing to resultsFallback: [] inside STATE worked. The reason is the same as you stated